# Every zeus command hangs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, zeus

I installed zeus, (included it in the Gemfile because I need to use it for guard). Now every command I run with zeus freeze. If I kill zeus, the command will abort and will give the following error

```
 zeusclient.go:86: EOF
```

Running `bundle exec guard -d` gives the following output

```
    Guard uses Libnotify to send notifications.
    Guard is now watching at '/home/pubudu/Projects/slnyaa-core'
    DEBUG (20:19:31): Command execution: hash stty
    DEBUG (20:19:31): Hook :start_begin executed for Guard::RSpec
    Guard::RSpec is running
    Running all specs
    DEBUG (20:19:31): Command execution: rspec --help
    DEBUG (20:19:31): Command execution: zeus rspec -f progress -r /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/guard-rspec-2.5.4/lib/guard/rspec/formatter.rb -f Guard::RSpec::Formatter --failure-exit-code 2 spec 
    zeusclient.go:86: EOF
    DEBUG (20:21:26): Command execution: hash stty
    DEBUG (20:21:26): Start interactor
    [Listen warning]:
    The blocking parameter of Listen::Listener#start is deprecated.
    Please use Listen::Adapter#start for a non-blocking listener and Listen::Listener#start! for a blocking one.
    > DEBUG (20:26:07): Stop interactor
    DEBUG (20:26:07): Command execution: hash stty
    DEBUG (20:26:07): Command execution: hash stty
    DEBUG (20:26:07): Start interactor
    > DEBUG (20:26:11): Stop interactor
    DEBUG (20:26:11): Command execution: hash stty
    DEBUG (20:26:11): Hook :stop_begin executed for Guard::RSpec
    Bye bye...
```

How to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you try starting zeus without guard?

Comment: Without starting guard? Tried that and ran different commands like zeus rspec and zeus console... same result